# Java constant specific class body private variable access

Tags: java, enums, static

Why does this not compile, and (relatedly) why is it that CC cannot access what I would have thought (maybe I'm wrong) its own (private) member variable i, when AA and BB can indeed do so?
How can CC access its own member variable?

Thank you.

```
enum TestEnum {
  AA(1000), BB(500), CC(100) {
    public int getI() {
      return i + 1;
    }
  };
  TestEnum(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  private int i;
  public int getI() {
    return this.i;
  }
}
```

javac output:

```
TestEnum.java:6: error: non-static variable i cannot be referenced from a static context
                 public int getI() { return i + 1; }
                                            ^
1 error
```

Comment: why do you have `getI` twice? what's with the brackets around the first one ? the semicolon should come directly after `CC(100)` ... See: http://jdoodle.com/a/mQF

Comment: i is private, and technically you're making a subtype, would be my guess.  Try super.getI instead of i.

Comment: That is probably the correct guess, but the output of of javac points to the fact that i is static, which does not makes sense at the moment. Another test could be making `i` `protected` instead of `private`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `super.getI() - 1` since you want to override the parent's method.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    AA(1000), BB(500), CC(100) {

        @Override
        public int getI() {
            return super.getI() - 1;
        }
    };

    private int i;

    TestEnum(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}
```

Alternatively make the field `protected` to access it directly (`return i - 1;`) as @oleg cherednik suggests. However, I prefer the solution above.

Comment: That was quick! Ah, of course. Thank you. That also suggests that each instance (or enum constant) of TestEnum is effectively a subclass, because subclasses also cannot access private variables of their superclass.  Is that correct?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why?

Comment: @JL_SO: so you can 1) up-vote this answer and 2) probably accept it as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have already tried to upvote it. I don't have enough points or whatever it is that they call it here.

Comment: Try again in 15 to 20 min

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: either do a `protected` field or call `super.getId()`. *I prefer to do first one, it is easier to read*. **Note:** think about enum body like `parent class`, and each constants like `children`, therefore your private field is not visible in `children AA, BB, CC`.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    AA(1000),
    BB(500),
    CC(100) {
        @Override
        public int getI() {
            return i + 1;
        }
    };

    protected final int i;

    TestEnum(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** It is preferable to have only `final` fields in the enum, because enum is like constant and should not have any variables.

Comment: I struggled to see what you'd changed here. You should add some text to your answer.